# Web Api Attribute Routing not getting to method with the data having question mark and ampersand

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have been liking the web api 2 atrribute routing a lot but I ran into a situation in which it is not working.

**javascript:**

```
var issueGetUri = '/GetIssue/?' + timestamp + '/';

  $.ajax({
     url: issueGetUri,
     type: 'Get',
     data: { id: qs["id"] },
     success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
     },
     error: function () {
         console.log("something seems wrong");
     }
 });
```

Essentially the **url** becomes:

```
http://localhost:24039/GetIssue/?1444864586786/&id=VGAJEGLS3G
```

I end up getting the "Something seems wrong

**WEB API**

```
[Route("GetIssue/{time}/id/{id}")]
[ResponseType(typeof (IssuesModel))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetIssueId(string timestamp, string id)
{
  .....
}
```

Can I keep the jquery ajax call from putting in **?** and **&** ?
Is that even the problem?

**Update,  Ok I fixed thx for the help  Works now!**

```
var issueGetUri = notLocal + '/GetIssue/id/' + qs["id"] + '/time/' + timestamp;

[Route("GetIssue/id/{id}/time/{time}")]
[ResponseType(typeof (IssuesModel))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetIssueId(string id, string time)
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: You should really remove the slash "/" from GetIssue. So it should be: '/GetIssue?' + timestamp + '/'; That is if you want to send parameters to your web api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I keep the jquery ajax call from putting in ? and & ?

So don't put them !

```js
//var issueGetUri = '/GetIssue/?' + timestamp + '/';

//          [Route("GetIssue/{time}/id/{id}")]
//                    °        °     °   °
//                    |         \    |   |--------------|
//                    |          \   |---------|        |
//                    v           v            v        v
var issueGetUri = '/GetIssue/' + timestamp + '/id/' + qs["id"];

  $.ajax({
     url: issueGetUri,
     type: 'Get',
  //   data: { id: qs["id"] },
     success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
     },
     error: function () {
         console.log("something seems wrong");
     }
 });
```

Comment: Ok, see,  but what if I did want to let the Route handle it?  Is it possible as well to have   Route[("GetIssue?{id}&time={time}")]  ?

Comment: I don't understand ! you choose a route and you use it ! you can't send 2 path once ! or maybe it is server-side you can handle 2 routes ?

Comment: I changed to this and it does not work:    
http://localhost:24039/GetIssue/id/VGAJEGLS3G/time/1444867181745 

  [Route("GetIssue/id/{id}/time/{time}")]

Comment: Sorry but i think is an issue from server side and i have no skill on [tag:asp.net-web-api2]

Comment: I got it now  thx ,   I not only had to fix the jquery ajax,  but the  Route in Web Api ,  ALONG with the Method needed to have matching incoming parameters that matches the Route ....    thx again